# Rotating object around a rotating one?

Tags: unity, c#, quaternion

I am developing a solar system animation in Unity3D. Planets rotates around sun. But ı have an issue simulating satellites like Moon. Moon should be rotating around world normally and moon should be rotating around World. Since World is rotating around Sun , i am having trouble about calculating  true rotation for moon. I don't want to use rotateAround() since it is deprecated. I need to make this done using Rotate().

this is my planetScript

```
public class planetScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject target;//target is Sun for World, World for Moon etc

    public float rotateRatioCenter;//1 degree for World
    private float rotateSpeedTarget;

    public float rotateRatioAround;//365 for World
    private float rotateSpeedAround;

    public float counter = 0;
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

     rotateSpeedTarget = rotateRatioCenter * gameMasterScript.rotateAroundCenterRatio;//  rotateRatioCenter * 1 , 
     rotateSpeedAround = rotateSpeedTarget * rotateRatioAround;
     float yRotate = transform.eulerAngles.y;

     transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotateSpeedAround);

     rotateAroundTarget();
    }

    void rotateAroundTarget()//this is the method should be optimized
    {
        Quaternion quaRot = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotateSpeedTarget, 0);
        transform.position = quaRot * (transform.position - target.transform.position) + target.transform.position;
    }
}
```

gameView
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to have one `GameObject` "orbit" around another (without `Transform.RotateAround()` would be to utilize the hierarchy.  Each planet can have an empty `GameObject` as its parent that's a child of its `target` like so

```
> Sun
   > Rotator (empty GameObject)
      > Planet
         > Rotator
            > Moon
   > Rotator
      > Planet
   > Rotator
      > Planet
```

Here's how you can accomplish that with your script:

```
public class planetScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject target;

    void Start() {
        m_rotator = new GameObject("rotator");
        m_rotator.transform.parent = target.transform;
        m_rotator.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero; // Might not need this

        this.gameObject.transform.parent = m_rotator.transform;
        this.gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(radius, 0, 0);
    }

    void Update() {
        // Rotate m_rotator
        m_rotator.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private GameObject m_rotator;
}
```

Also, as a note, this makes sense if you're using `Transform.Rotate()` but `Transform.RotateAround()` is not deprecated and you're free to use it.  Not sure where you got that info from but it's supported in the latest release of Unity.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. World->rotater->moon. Since World is rotating around sun this situation makes rotater rotate unexpected. If i had 2 level hierarchy this would probably work. I had the same issue with my script .I solved the issue assigning satellite object to my planet script. But your idea looks very practical and logical.